# Multiple connections to APNS from Java provider implementation

Tags: java, iphone, ios, multithreading, apple-push-notifications

Just start scaling APNS provider program unfortunately I am really new to networking protocol implementation.
The provider now only runs on one thread and it's just handling a tiny amount of notifications. Now I want to increase its capability to send significantly more than before.
My questions are:

1. According to Apple doc I can maintain multiple connections to gateways. So my understanding is that I run multithreads in the provider program and maintain a separate connection in each. Is this right?
2. It first one is right the real difficulty for me comes: my program polls a queue database every 5 seconds to check new message that's to be sent. I do not think it's a good idea for all the threads to poll this same database because there should be duplicate message same to users. How to solve this problem?

I have seen the connections pooling but I do not really understand what that is. Is that the thing I need to study and use? If it is can someone offer an brief explanation regarding what it is and how to use it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: are you talking about implementing a server or client or both?!

Answer (score 0):

Your first assumption is reasonable.  Each thread should have its own connection.

As for the second point,  the access to the DB that contains the new messages should be synchronized. For example,  you can access that DB by a synchronized method that fetches a message  or several messages that haven't been processed yet, and marks them as being processed. Two threads can't access that method at the same time, and therefore won't get the same messages.

Another option is to put the messages in memory in a blocking quoue (with the DB only serving for backup in case of a crash). The threads can request an item from the queue,  which would block them until an item is available.